# Need advise on linking apache and tomcat

Tags: servlets, ssl, https, apache-2.2

I have been searching this for hours with no luck. I have a web server that uses https on Apache2. I also have installed tomcat7 on the same server to run some Java webapp on it. I need to keep my https port 443 on Apache but forward the requests to the Java webapp to tomcat. I tried to use mod_jk to redirect the requests to tomcat but I failed. Most tutorials talk about redirecting plain http requests not https. 
I also could not let tomcat use https on 8443. I'm following the steps [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) but facing errors.

The question: 
Can I redirect https traffic to tomcat without installing https on tomcat? 
Is there a good tutorial you can recommend to me?

Answer (score 1):

> The question: Can I redirect https traffic to tomcat without installing https on tomcat?

Yes. just install an AJP connector in Tomcat and use mod_proxy and mod_proxy_ajp in Apache. Or an HTTP connector with mod_proxy_http.

> Is there a good tutorial you can recommend to me?

See the documentation for the modules I mentioned.

I'm astonished you weren't able to find anything on this topic, but looking in the wrong place (such as here) won't help. Question belongs on serverfault.com.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Of course I have found lots of tutorials but I was confused, none worked for me.

Comment: @hsnm With a vague statement like 'no luck' it's impossible to tell what you meant, but the Apache documentation was sufficient for me.