# Configure Proxy Server

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, proxy

Here is what I want to do:

I have a Java application that supports execution of any HTTP/HTTPS URL with or without proxy server. I could able to do it with HTTP and HTTPS. But I am getting stuck while trying with proxy server. I have no experience working with proxy server.

What I tried to use Apache HTTP Server as proxy server and tomcat as app server.

My doubt is:

How can I configure a proxy server? What are the steps needs to be followed for that? I tried reading the the Apache document from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html. But I understood a little about how exactly to proceed.

I have also tried with the below links:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244881/proxy-server-configuration
2. [Need advise on linking apache and tomcat](https://serverfault.com/questions/438387/need-advise-on-linking-apache-and-tomcat)

But did not get how to proceed.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: So, you're trying to set up a proxy server or do you just need to configure your app to _use_ a proxy server?

Comment: @squillman Thanks for your response. I want to configure my application to use a proxy server.